# maven module build. Not specifying version with children modules

Tags: maven, module

We have a multi-module build. I have a parent module that builds 17 other modules and one of those modules itself is another multi-module build that builds three others.

In my parent module:

```
<groupId>com.veggicorp.foobar</groupId>
<artifactId>foobar-parent</artifactId>
<version>5.4.3</version>

<properties>
    <!-- Definition of versions for third party jars -->
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Another way to specify dependencies throughout the project -->
</dependencyManagement>

<modules>
    <!-- List o' Modules -->
</modules>
```

By using properties to specify versions (and using dependencyManagement), I found I can get rid of almost any sort of version numbering in the child modules. This makes it very simple to maintain a complex project since most of the changes will take place in the parent. When we do a new version, I don't have to update 21 other `pom.xml` files.

However, there is one sore spot: I have to specify the parent version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.veggicorp.foobar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3</version> <!-- Must Specify -->
</parent>

<artifactId>foo-server</artifactId>
<!-- No need for a version -->

<build>
    ....
```

Note that I don't need to specify the version of the child. It takes the parent's version by default. However, I have to fill in the parent's version number despite the fact that all of this sits in a single Git repository, and that all of the modules are unique for this project and are not used anywhere else. We won't even be deploying these modules' jars to our Maven repository. It's one big gigantic build.

I know I can use the version plugin to update all of these modules, but that means our developers must remember to use that plugin when they create a new version of the project. (I don't have much faith in our developers. Heck, we have directions on our wiki on [how to tie your shoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ia8U-Yb-tkI).)

So, is there a way where our child modules -- which get checkedout with the parent module in a single big Git repo -- can avoid having the parent version number embedded in them?

Comment: I hope you are using SNAPSHOT's ? Are you doing OSGi development?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you have to include the parent information in all the child modules and that information has to include the version.

However once you have set this up you can use the versions plugin to mange the versions of all your poms see http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

example, from the top level:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1
```

will change all the children and the parent.

Comment: I know about the version plugin, but the developers use Eclipse and most aren't very good at Maven. I do a lot of hand holding. Just getting them to change the version number of a simple jar project when they release it is hard enough.

Comment: @DavidW. So you are developing OSGi...If so do you use Tycho ? There exist a tycho-versions plugin which also handled changing MANIFEST.MF, feature.xml etc.

Comment: Starting with [Maven 3.5.0-beta-1](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) this is [not really true anymore](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/04/02/maven-pom-files-without-a-version-in-it/).

Comment: @khmarbaise  Not using OSGI because the jars are used no where else. We're not even putting these jars into our Maven repo.

Comment: @khmarbaise I got excited by this, and downloaded 3.5.0, but then I realize this is the child revision and not the parent. I still need to specify the parent version -- even though the parent `pom.xml` is in the parent directory and these child projects will never, ever be built or deployed independently.